# APK file Exporting Error

Tags: proguard

When i tried to export my APK file, this is my Error Log

```
[2014-04-02 12:41:06 - 8bitMaker] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-04-02 12:41:06 - 8bitMaker] proguard.ParseException: Expecting java type before ' ' in line 95 of file 'G:\Workspace\8bitMaker\proguard-project.txt',
[2014-04-02 12:41:06 - 8bitMaker]   included from argument number 4
[2014-04-02 12:41:06 - 8bitMaker]   at     proguard.ConfigurationParser.checkJavaIdentifier(ConfigurationParser.java:1187)
[2014-04-02 12:41:06 - 8bitMaker]   at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseMemberSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:842)
[2014-04-02 12:41:06 - 8bitMaker]   at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:697)
[2014-04-02 12:41:06 - 8bitMaker]   at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseKeepClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:490)
[2014-04-02 12:41:06 - 8bitMaker]   at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:139)
[2014-04-02 12:41:06 - 8bitMaker]   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:484)
```

This is where the line 95 is

```
    -keepclasseswithmembers class **.R$** 
{
public static <fields>;
}
****Line 95****   -keepclassmembers class * 
{ @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;}
-keep class * extends android.view.View 
{ 

  public <init>(android.content.Context); 
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet); 
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int); 
  void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}
```

Based on the log file, the error code is 1 and the error is at line 95. Anyone has any idea to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if there isn't some invisible control character on or near that line.